# Ajax calls from static.domain.com to domain.com

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that you cannot make ajax requests crossdomain or even to a different subdomain of the same domain. I have a `static.domain.com` where all my javascript files reside (static content). All the javascript files are included on `domain.com`. There is no inline javascript code `domain.com`.

**Question:** I want a solution to make `ajax POST requests` from `static.domain.com` to `domain.com`. Is that possible and to behave the same in different browsers?

**Later Edit:** I don't want to use `jsonp`. I want to send `POST requests` and `read the response`. Some of the requests include file uploading.

Comment: TRY: `datatype:jsonp`

Comment: i think we can request on cross domain

Comment: Have you tried adding a crossdomain.xml file that will allow the crossdomain requests?

Comment: Ironic: call from *static* domain.

Comment: I just wanted to edit my question to say that I don't want to use jsonp. I want to make post requests.

Comment: May be this can help you out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: @TasosK. — It's JavaScript, not Flash or Silverlight.